# My server is starting Webrick instead of Unicorm/Nginx on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn, webrick

I've followed these steps in order to have a Unicorn/Nginx app running:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-14-04
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

I've done everything indicated there with exception of the databases instructions (because I'm going to use Mongo). However when I execute (ip edited):

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails server --binding=123.456.789.01
```

a Webrick server is started:

```
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in production on http://123.456.789.01:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
```

Is there something I need to check to get the production setup working fine? I don't know what I need to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have skipped some steps in the [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) you have mentioned... After you install unicorn and nginx you should be able to start them:

```
sudo service unicorn_appname start
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: I have done this. I've just retry those steps, restarting both unicorn and nginx. No errors reported. I tried to restart the server and this time I got:
Booting WEBrick
A server is already running. Check /home/user/appname/tmp/pids/server.pid.

Is there a way to see if the loaded page is actually coming from unicorn and not from webrick?

Comment: You don't have to run rails server (webrick)... Kill all the services and start just the nginx. You should see the nginx page... Now start the unicorn and, if the configs are correct, you should see your application. Please note that unicorn and nginx are replacement for webrick.

Comment: so, you are saying I don't need to run: RAILS_ENV=production rails server --binding=server_public_IP 
once that unicorn/nginx are running

Comment: Yep... You don't have to run that. Take a look on this tutorial as well http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/setting-up-your-production-server-with-nginx-and-unicorn

Comment: Thanks for the response. In brief my problem was that nginx needed to restart and that I was running an non required rails server that started webrick